# run Mysql command from host machine in docker image

Tags: mysql, bash, docker

I would like to pipe a sql file to MySQL image from host machine, but I am having following outputs.

**I can access the  mysql-pubsub-3.2.0.sql file**

```
> % docker exec -it docker-mysql ls /var/lib/mysql/mysql-pubsub-3.2.0.sql                                 
/var/lib/mysql/mysql-pubsub-3.2.0.sql
```

**But cannot route same file to mysql command script**

```
> % docker exec -it docker-mysql mysql -u XXX -p 'XXXX' < /var/lib/mysql/mysql-pubsub-3.2.0.sql
zsh: no such file or directory: /var/lib/mysql/mysql-pubsub-3.2.0.sql
```

Comment: `docker exec -it docker-mysql sh -c "mysql -u XXX -p 'XXXX' < /var/lib/mysql/mysql-pubsub-3.2.0.sql"`

Comment: > % docker exec -it docker-mysql sh -c "mysql -u XXX -p 't!XYZ' < /var/lib/mysql/mysql-pubsub-3.2.0.sql"
zsh: event not found: XYZ

Comment: Since password having !,  I am having below error, how can I overcome this

Comment: `docker exec -it docker-mysql sh -c 'mysql -u XXX -p "XXXX" < /var/lib/mysql/mysql-pubsub-3.2.0.sql'`

Comment: sorry but, after typing suggested command, first password prompt is shown, then got following error, Enter password: 
ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 't!XYZ'

Comment: I've found the problem, after passing database name via -p instead of password, it works. docker exec -it docker-mysql sh -c "mysql -u username -p databaseName < /var/lib/mysql/mysql-pubsub-3.2.0.sql"